# How to get back to printf

Tags: c

After confirming the number is positive or negative, I want to go back to the first initial `printf`.

what should i do?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main()
{
    int a, b, c, max;

    printf("Entry bill 1 :  "); scanf("%i", &a);
    printf("Entry bill 2 :  "); scanf("%i", &b);
    printf("Entry bill 3 :  "); scanf("%i", &c);

    if ((a > b) && (a > c))
        max = a;
    if ((b > a) && (b > c))
        max = b;
    if ((c > a) && (c > b))
        max = c;
    printf("Bil terbesar adalah : %i \n", max);
    if (max > 0)
        printf("Bil tersebut adalah positif \n");
    if (max < 0)
        printf("Bil tersebut adalah negatif \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But seriously, sounds like you're looking for a loop of some sort. You'll have to give us more information, particularly the exit conditions, for us to offer meaningful aid.

Comment: Unrelated advice: You should use `else if` for mutually exclusive conditions. And use `else` for the last block.

Comment: BTW, you don't set `max` if any of the inputs are equal to each other. You could use `>=` instead of `>`.

Comment: Chuck a `goto` in there.. She'll be right mate.  Just kidding, don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

maaybe you can use do-while loop and add some condition looping, like this

```
main()
{
boolean isloop = true; 
do{
  int a,b,c,max;

  printf("Entry bill 1 :  "); scanf("%i",&a);
  printf("Entry bill 2 :  "); scanf("%i",&b); 
  printf("Entry bill 3 :  "); scanf("%i",&c);

  if((a>b)&&(a>c))
    max=a;
  if((b>a)&&(b>c))
    max=b;
  if((c>a)&&(c>b))
    max=c;
  printf("Bil terbesar adalah : %i \n",max);
  if(max>0)
    printf("Bil tersebut adalah positif \n");
  if(max<0)
    printf("Bil tersebut adalah negatif \n");

  // you can setting value variable isLoop = false, to stop looping

}while(isLoop);   

return 0;       

}
```